# promedio de edades a partir de la fecha de naciemiento? postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Hola como hago para que me muestre el promedio de edades en PostgreSQL desde la fecha de nacimiento.

Dejo aca el codigo, es de prueba:

```
Create database prueba;

create table usuario(
    id serial primary key not null,
    nombre varchar(20),
    fecha_nacimiento date
);

insert into usuario (nombre,fecha_nacimiento)values('ezequiel','1992/02/14');
insert into usuario (nombre,fecha_nacimiento)values('fernanda','199/02/07');
insert into usuario (nombre,fecha_nacimiento)values('pedro','1998/02/14');
insert into usuario (nombre,fecha_nacimiento)values('pichulin','2005/02/14');
```

Intente hacer esto pero no sirvio:

```
select AGE(fecha_nacimiento) as edad, avg(edad) 
from usuario
```

Comment: Bienvenido Ezequiel Tomassini a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: ¿Es esto lo que buscas: `select avg(AGE(fecha_nacimiento)) as prom_edad from usuario`?

Comment: Si!! Era eso. Muchas gracias!!!